# JS Date missing time and zone after inserting into Postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I looked at the [node-postgres docs on Date](https://node-postgres.com/features/types)

Here's what I tried myself in JS:

`const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();`

When I used that for the postgres insert, I don't get back a time or timezone.  I get back for example: `2020-09-29 00:00:00+00`

I'm using `Timestamp with Timezone` data type on my postgres `created_date` field that this is stored in.

I suppose I'd have to give it the **local** but I don't understand **local** very well.  If I'm in say Chicago, would I put US for the local?  How does that work for those in other countries using my DB and me creating timestamps for them for my created_date?

**Use Case**: I'm simply trying to store the created date for a **new user who joined my website** and include timestamp and timezone.  Users could be from around the world.

Comment: Not enough info. How do you receive the timezone of the users in the first place? What exactly does your insert code look like? And what's the query where you don't get back the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

I went with this. I don't know if ISO is what I need or if I need to be figuring out their timezones then specifying local or what but:

Using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/tour.html)

`const now = DateTime.local().toString();`

produced this in the DB: `2020-11-08 05:23:17.929+00`

I guess this is good enough? I don't know.